# How to compare unicode and datetime.timedelta values?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I have a value as unicode. Its a digit say "4". I need to compare it with `datetime.timedelta` value `"42 days, 9:46:21"`. How to convert them both in same format either to do a comparison or a subtraction?

In below code, TimeDiffRestoCurrent is a datetime.timedelta and SLA_Time is a unicode string.

```
if  TimeDiffRestoCurrent < SLA_Time:
    print()
```

Error I found was:

```
    if  TimeDiffRestoCurrent < SLA_Time:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `s` holds your value as unicode in seconds, and `td` holds your timedelta value.

First, convert `s` to float:

```
t1 = float(s) # assuming it can be parsed to float
```

Then, convert td to float as well by doing the following:

```
t2 = td.total_seconds()
```

You can now compare them as they are both in seconds. If `s` is in minutes, hours or days, do the appropriate multiplication.